# Radon–Nikodym derivative Relation to derivative in calculus?

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I am reading chapter 3 of Folland's Real Analysis Book, where it introduces the Radon-Nikodym Derivative of a sigma finite signed measure with respect to another sigma finite positive measure.

> Let $\nu$ be a $\sigma$-finite signed measure and $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite positive measure on $(X,M)$. There exists unique $\sigma$-finite signed measure $\lambda,\rho$ on the space such that $$\lambda \perp \mu \text{  } \rho << \mu \text{  and  } \nu=\lambda +\rho$$ and there is an $\mu$-integrable function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $d\rho=f d\mu$ where $f$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative.

I am just wondering if this is somehow related to the derivative in calculus in anyway, since Riemann integral of a continuous fct on bounded interval is equal to Lebesgue integral and Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite?
Or maybe this question is kind of stupid and they are not related in any way.

Comment: These two derivatives are indeed related. You can how if you read about the Stieltjes integral: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral . Look particularly at the discussion of Differentiable $g(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are very much related.

You may be familiar with [Lebesgue's Differentation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem). In the special case where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$, and for a $\sigma$-finite measure $\nu$ with $\nu << \lambda$ we have $$\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\int\limits_{x-h}^{x+h}{\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}(y)}d\lambda(y)}{2h}= \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\nu([x-h,x+h])}{2h} \quad \text{$\lambda$-a.e.}$$

And this in turn is the differential quotient of the function $f(x)=\nu((-\infty,x])$

A more general version of the theorem holds for Radon measures. It can be shown that if $\nu << \mu$, then $$\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}(x)=\lim\limits_{r \to 0} \frac{\nu({B_{r}(x)})}{\mu(B_{r}(x))} \quad \text{$\mu$-a.e.}$$

see  Theorem 1.30  in

*Evans, Lawrence Craig; Gariepy, Ronald F.*, Measure theory and fine properties of functions, Textbooks in Mathematics. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press (ISBN 978-1-4822-4238-6/hbk). p.50 (2015). [ZBL1310.28001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1310.28001).